# How to mask IP address when generating verification email in Django-Rest-Framework backend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, server

I am building an application with `Django-Rest-Framework` as my backend and `React-Native` as front-end.

When a user registers an activation email is generated which is something of this sort

```
http://192.168.0.109:8000/api/auth/register/account-confirm-email/MTU:1mmAOY:3c3emcDMtURa4euwcg3a-Iwb3YYh3pdmM4Dme8emwN0/
```

Which gives out the IP-address of my hosted server.

How do I mask this IP address - `http://192.168.0.109`?

Comment: Do you have a hostname/DNS to send in place of the IP?

Comment: you can use an url shortener service, like bitly.com